# $A^T A$ eigenvalue bounding

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix with real entries.

Is there anything like any eigenvalue of $A^tA \leq \max({1,\lambda^2})$ where 
$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and max is taken over all eigenvalues?

Comment: How to show it @JonasMeyer? Yes yor assumptions should be in my guess!

Comment: Yobo: I added the assumption of real entries to the question.  I deleted my comment in part because it implied an incorrect statement base on my backwards thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2):

This is a thought:
Let svd of $A=U\Sigma V^T$. Thus $A^TA=V\Sigma^2 V^T$. Thus, eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are squares of singular values of those of $A$. Thus, what you actually require is that the squared singular values of a matrix should be less than the maximum among the absolute squared values of its eigenvalues, i.e 
\begin{align}
\sigma_i^2\leq max(|\lambda_k|^2),~\forall i
\end{align}
where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. I don't think it is true in general, unless $A$ has some kind of properties.

Comment: This should be correct always?? There is no suspicious here??

Comment: Yes, it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $A$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix with all its eigenvalues being real. The inequality is false in general (see chaohuang's answer for a counterexample), but it is true in each of the following circumstances (exercises):

- $A$ is real symmetric (in this case, $A$ is guaranteed to have only real eigenvalues),
- $A$ is a [doubly stochastic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) (hint: [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem)),
- the norm of every column of $A$ does not exceed $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ (hint: for any unit vector $x$, we have $\|Ax\|\le\sum_i|x_j|\|a_{\ast j}\|\le\|x\|\ \left\|\left(\|a_{\ast 1}\|,\ldots,\|a_{\ast n}\|\right)\right\|$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequalty),
- the norm of every row of $A$ does not exceed $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$,
- $\|A\|_1\|A\|_\infty\le1$, where $\|A\|_1$ and $\|A\|_\infty$ are respectively the maximum absolute column sum norm and the maximum absolute row sum norm of $A$ (hint: $\rho(A^TA)\le\|A^TA\|_1\le\|A^T\|_1\|A\|_1$).

Comment: Why is it false in general could you give a counterexample? Thank you..

Comment: @Yobo See the answer of chaohuang for a counterexample.

Answer (score -1):

We know that $A$ and $A^t$ have the same set of eigenvaluse, and we also know that the matrix products $AB$ and $BA$ have the same sets of eigenvalues. These two bits of information may be of help. Good luck!